# Why the difference with ListIterator vs Stream

Tags: java, javafx, iterator, java-stream

We have a Dictionary txt file we converted to a String[ ] simpleArray
We seldom work with array's so this one was beyond our comfort zone
It has 466552 items in this format 40 abacterial
When we checking for a misspelled word it is blazing fast
When we go back to the list and check for the correct spelling of a word we were using ListIterator
We found the results odd based on the search term
So we tried to use Java 8 Streams with filters and lambda

Here are the results using the ListIterator with the search term **"some"**

> somebodies someday somegate someonell someone's Somerdale
>   somersaulting
>  somerseted Somersetshire Somersville somesthesis
>   somet sometime someway
>  somewhatly somewhen somewheres somewhiles
>   somic

Here are the results using the ListIterator with the search term **"someo"** and **"someon"**

> someone'll somepart

Here are the results using the Steams with filters and lambda the search term is **"someon"**

> someone  someonell  someone'll  someones  someone's

**The question is have we constructed the ListIterator code correctly?**
 
While the code runs it dose not produce reliable results

**We would appreciate knowing if the Stream code could be constructed differently**

The goal was to add the items to a listview for now the results are in a textarea
We have not used the listview before

```
}if(found != true){

for(indexSC = 0; indexSC < simpleArray.length;indexSC++){
if(simpleArray[indexSC].toLowerCase().contains(txtTest.getText().trim().toLowerCase())){
// array stream foreach filter results to textarea javafx
List<String> cs = Arrays.asList(simpleArray);

ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
cs.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("someon"))
  //.forEach(System.out::println); 
.forEach(list :: add);   
String aL = list.toString();
System.out.println("!!!! aL "+aL);
String La = list.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]","").replace(",", " ");
System.out.println("@@@@ Stream "+La);

txaML.appendText(La);
txaML.appendText("\n");
//list.forEach(System.out::println);


ListIterator<String> listItr = cs.listIterator();
System.out.println("%%%% Second Find "+simpleArray[indexSC]+" At indexSC "+indexSC+" L "+simpleArray[indexSC].length());
txaML.clear();
while(listItr.hasNext()){
    if(listItr.next().startsWith("someon")){

        txaML.appendText(listItr.next());
        txaML.appendText("\n");
        //txaML.appendText(listItr.next().intern());
        //txaML.appendText("\n");
        System.out.println("!!!! ListIterator "+listItr.next());
        //System.out.println("!!!!!! Next intern "+listItr.next().intern());

    }  
}
```

Comment: We are trying to improve your Stream code I hope they do not close this question! As we have been working on the same concept. I guess it does not pay to be curious and decided the best way to code a situation. that is a lot of code in the Stream method

Comment: @James_Duh We edited the question. Because we seldom use the ListIterator or the Streams with lambda I know it runs but the lambda seems to be a cobbled together mess. Fix if you like Who's file are you using for the Dictionary ?

Comment: Your code is hard to follow. I am guessing that is due to how you indented the code. You can look [here](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/) for some ideas. This question is hard to understand as-is. If my understanding of the question is correct, it's not a question for StackOverflow. This question my be better for CodeReview. I am not really sure.

Comment: @Sedrick We have a dictionary file that we use to check the text in a TextArea after the misspelled words are found with enter the found !=true method where we want to go back in to the same dictionary and use the contains term to search for words that are correct. We then Stream or Iterate over the new "list" looking for correct spelling suggestions. Each method Streams and Iterator produced different results. YEP we did look at the Post you suggested. YES we are not good at formatting code when we are slamming a test project together Thanks not sure we would put this on CodeReview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> We would appreciate knowing if the Stream code could be constructed
>   differently

We added a few item to your project namely a ComboBox and a ListView
Why ? If you plan on selecting the information generated by the Stream the TextArea is a real bear when it comes to selecting items (Text)
We noticed that you had an ArrayList list that the Stream added data to
So no need for all that replace code. We added a SelectionModel listener to the ListView

Here is the code with your old remnant code
This is all you need for the ComboBox

```
 public void CboSelect(){
 months = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
}

@FXML
public void getSP(){
    String selected = cboSP.getValue().toString();
    System.out.println("S S S selected "+selected); 
}
```

Here is the new work of Art ha ha

```
        }if(found != true){

        lvListView.setStyle("-fx-font-size:18.0;-fx-background-color: white;");
        for(indexSC = 0; indexSC < simpleArray.length;indexSC++){
        if(simpleArray[indexSC].toLowerCase().contains(txtTest.getText().trim().toLowerCase())){
        // array stream foreach filter results to textarea javafx
        List<String> cs = Arrays.asList(simpleArray);

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        cs.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("someon"))
          //.forEach(System.out::println); 
        .forEach(list :: add);   
        //String aL = list.toString();
        //System.out.println("!!!! aL "+aL);
        //La = list.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]","").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "\n");
        int L = list.size();
        for(int X = 0; X < L;X++){
        String A = (String) list.get(X);
        cboSP.getItems().add(A);
        txaML.appendText(A);
        txaML.appendText("\n");
        lvListView.getItems().add(A);
        System.out.println(" = = L "+L+" Num "+A);
        }

        lvListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println(newValue);});
```

We could not find much on the behavior of ListIterators with regards to performance
We looked a number of SO posts about Streams seems to be the new Java 8 thing

Comment: Great improvement We need to work on lambda's the Streams was from another SO post and all the author did was use a System.out.println() We realized after building the test project with a TextArea that was a big NO NO Thanks for the Work of Art.

Comment: Why are both of you using "we" the way you are?